# Cleats and shoes

Tags: shoes

I have some cleats that say Look Patent, what are the compatible look pedals?
I am pretty sure that that is what the cleats say but correct me if I am wrong.

[image: Look cleat on the bottom of a shoe]

Comment: Are you sure that's a cleat?   Metal or plastic?  If it's plastic it's almost certainly a "place-holder" that is intended to be replaced by a cleat.

Comment: yeh, I am pretty sure it is a cleat

Comment: @daniel r Hicks I’ve never seen a metal look cleat. They are always plastic.

Comment: @Andrew - I've never seen a plastic cleat.

Comment: @DanielRHicks - you must not be very familiar with clipless pedals. Look pedals with plastic cleats were the dominant road bike clipless system for a couple of decades and are still quite common. They are the reason that so many road bike shoes come with 3-bolt pattern soles.

Comment: @Andrew - The cleats on my shoes are metal.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot correct you if you are wrong because I can't see your cleats. I assume you have 3-bolt cleats. Look also makes 2-bolt cleats, but that's not what they're known for.

Your cleats are probably compatible with Look Keo pedals; in addition to Look themselves, there are a lot of other companies making Keo-compatible pedals. Look has an older design called "Delta" that is not compatible with Keo, so if your cleats look really old, they might be Deltas. I don't think anyone is still making Delta pedals.

Note that Shimano SPD-SL pedals are very similar but incompatible; note also that Shimano SPD pedals are completely unrelated to SPD-SL pedals.

Comment: Photo added - that's definitely a Keo cleat so you can firm up your answer.

Comment: Concur - and they're barely worn at all.  Perhaps a ride or two at most, or even just walking around.

Comment: Ok Thanks so what pedals would I need

Comment: As it seems there are different subcategories of the keo pedals

Comment: It's mostly a matter of how much you want to spend to get lighter pedals and fancier materials.

Comment: @Asher: All Look Keo pedals are 'born' equal concerning the cleats. So any of their vast range of road pedals will fit.

Comment: I wouldn’t say deltas are only really old. Many people are still making and using them. In fact that’s the style used by Peloton on their bikes. (Of course you can change, but all of the Peloton branded pedals are delta)

Comment: It could be also argued that Peloton is not up to date with current standards or cheapin out by copying an obsolete and probably cheaper to license system.